# Trying to understand strange behavior with login button workaround in ASP

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

In trying to prevent Anti-XRF token failures (when a user assaults the 'login' button after it has already been pressed and the page is already loading) I decided to make the ASP button not visible, and put an HTML button in it's place. The JS attached to the HTML button checks if the page is valid (I have a required field validator for the username textbox as well as the password textbox) and if it is, the HTML button is disabled, and the actual ASP button click is triggered.

The main test case that I am having problems with and can't seem to understand is when I type in a WRONG username and password. The Button is disabled properly and the ASP button is clicked, the page reloads with a 'Wrong username and password' message from the Login_Click function in the behind code, but then at this point regardless of if something is typed into either texbox or not, after one 'login click' the button is disabled (meaning it passed the if(Page_isValid) line) and the alert ("asp button has been clicked") is shown which I have directly after the line that triggers the asp button, but it seems that the asp button is in fact never triggered as the page does not load and the breakpoint which I have at the login_click function in the behind code is never reached. Am I mis-using the RequiredField Validators or the Page_IsValid functionality? Or is there a better way to accomplish this? All relevent code is below. I hope that I provided enough information for assistance, if you need me to clarify or add anything at all please let me know.

Validators:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="tbUserName" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" onpropertychange ="reEnable()" ControlToValidate="tbUserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." EnableClientScript="true" />
    <br>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tbPassword">Password:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" onpropertychange ="reEnable()" ControlToValidate="tbPassword" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." EnableClientScript="true" />
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function clientClick() {

        if (Page_IsValid) {
            alert("Page is valid")
            document.getElementById('btnLoginSubmit').disabled = true;
            alert("HTML BUTTON DISABLED")
            document.getElementById('<%= btnLogin.ClientID %>').click();
            alert("asp button has been clicked")
        }

        else { document.getElementById('btnLoginSubmit').disabled = false; }

            return true;
    }


    function reEnable() {

        document.getElementById('btnLoginSubmit').disabled = false;
        return true;
    }
```

Login_Click method:

```
  protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnLogin.Enabled = false;

        String adPath = "LDAP://xxx-xxx.xxxxxxxxx.net:999/XX=Xxxx-Xxxxx-Xxxxxx,DC=xxxxxxxx,DC=net"; //Fully-qualified Domain Name
        CentralLogin.ADRoleProvider.LdapAuthentication adAuth = new CentralLogin.ADRoleProvider.LdapAuthentication(adPath);
        try
        {
            if (true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated("xxxxxxxxx.net", tbUserName.Text, tbPassword.Text))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name.ToString(), false);

                String groups = "no groups";

                //Create the ticket, and add the groups.
                bool isCookiePersistent = false;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, tbUserName.Text,
                DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups);

                //Encrypt the ticket.
                String encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

                //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
                HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                if (true == isCookiePersistent)
                {
                    authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
                }
                //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                //You can redirect now.
                //Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(tbUserName.Text, false));
                Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(tbUserName.Text, true));

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(authTicket);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(authCookie);

            }
            else
            {
                errorLabel.Text = "Authentication Failed. Username or Password are Incorrect.";
                tbPassword.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //errorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
            errorLabel.Text = "Authentication Failed. Username or Password are Incorrect.";
            tbPassword.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

}

If you have read this far, you're already a champion. Thank you.

Comment: In your client click function I think you need to return false in your else otherwise the form will still submit if the page isn't valid (which you don't want it to do)

Comment: I just tried this. Unfortunately nothing changed. Furthermore, after a wrong UN and PW attempt, it somehow thinks that the page is valid even if I leave one of the textboxes completely blank.